# Permutation-How to approach problems that have "At Least" requirements?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to solve this problem on my own yet it is somewhat tricky because I have never seen this type of problem before.

Say I need to create a **10-character** password from **uppercase letters** and **digits** with following requirements:

- The password must contain **at least** $3$ uppercase letters
- The password must contain **at least** $1$ digit
- The digits **cannot** be repeated

I tried to apply the permutation formula $\boldsymbol{n!/(n-r)!}$ to this problem yet I still cannot see the pattern, and my original thought was that since at least 3 character must be letters, I only had $7$ choices left, and then I just got stuck because I could not make it work on the digits part.

I would be much appreciated with the help, thank you

Comment: The permutation formula only applies when no object can be repeated, which is not the case for the uppercase letters here.

Answer (score 1):

[choose spaces for alphabets and insert]*[permute digits in remaining space]

Assuming English alphabet,
With $3$ repeatable alphabets, $7$ distinct digits, we get $\binom{10}3\cdot{26}^3\cdot P^{10}_7$

Continue thus upto  $9$ repeatable alphabets and one distinct digit, viz $\binom{10}9\cdot{26}^9\cdot P^{10}_1$ and add up computations from $3 \;thru\; 9$ repeatable alphabets

Comment: Thank you, that really gave me an insight on how to solve this problem, but there are still quite a few things that I don't understand. I understand that add computations from 3 through 9 part, but I don't get it why do we need to multiply 26 to the power of 3 through 9, and that would be a really huge number. Would you care to elaborate more on that? Thank you

Comment: Well, if you used only alphabets, the number of three letter passwords would be $26\times26\times26\; = 26^3$, wouldn't it, because you are allowed to repeat a letter, each slot has $26$ possibilities. This is just the *multiplication principle*

Comment: Oh, I get it now, I just didn't expect it to be such a great number, thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome !